# Share 1 hdd to PC and PS3

Tags: hard-drive, usb, switch, kvm-switch, ps3

I have HDD connected to PS3 via USB. Is there any device to allow connecting this HDD to computer also? My goal is to have this HDD connected to both PS3 and PC and then on PC there supposed to be application that would switch this HDD from PS3 to HDD.

I've found USB Sharing switch (for example http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sharing-USB-2-0-Switch-Hub-2-PC-to-1-Printer-Scanner-Newrok-Switcher-Free-Shipping/859746228.html) but will it work with PS3?

P.S. I need to connect via USB only. Sharing HDD and then access it from PS3 is not the option for me.

Comment: If your goal is to share the same storage with both devices at the sametime that won't be possible unless both devices suports network drives and I don't believe the PS3 does.

Comment: nope, not at the same time. 1 device at the same time. Just would like to have to be able to switch them somehow.

Comment: USB Switch would accomplish that.  Although you understand that PS3 OS does not understand NTFS and Windows does not understand the file system used by the PS3 natively right?  You would want to disconnect the drive on the PC side, before you switch which device the drive will be connected to, to avoid data loss